# :// Would Like To Use Your Current Location

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

I am build an mobile app using ionic capacitor. In the webview, I am using javascript:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

When the user first time install and open the app, it pop up an alert as below:

[image]

Now Apple asked me to change the description :// to be more meaningful.

> Please revise the purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file for the
> location to explain why your app needs access.
>
> You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list
> editor in Xcode.

I tried all location related properties but none of them are changing the description in the alert box.

Ideas/help please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: go to your `info.plist` file inside your xcode and change this description. and write why your application used location.

Comment: Im also facing the same issue when I launch target url using  InAppBrowser from cordova. I have used navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in the target url to get the geo location on click of the button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the geolocation plugin, you need to change privacy descriptions in `Info.plist` as per the [guide](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/geolocation#ios-notes). Look for these two keys:

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the original post. Please check new attached images. 
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription is adding description for the other alert box. The alert box in OP is from Webview.

Comment: @harryfeng when does the alert box show up? After you already gave the permission? Can you explain the architecture a bit more? Are you using the OOB webview?

Answer (score 1):

That's a WKWebView bug, you should report it to WebKit team, it's supposed to show the name of your app, but it's not
https://bugs.webkit.org/

You can use [Geolocation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation) plugin instead of web geolocation

Comment: Thanks. This works. Using the Geolocation plugin, it works on both web and capacitor mobile. In the capacitor mobile, there won't be alert box from the webview any more. Only the pop up with the map one asking for location permission.

Comment: @jcesarmobile and harryfeng - I am using cordova-plugin-geolocation but I still keep on getting the same error (even though the info.plist has all the needed properties). How did you guys resolve that?

Comment: @harryfeng (tagging harry as well, in case he knows)

Comment: The plugin is probably not installed correctly, or you are using it before device ready event has fired, or you didn’t add the cordova.js in the index.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with the plugin you are using to get the Geolocation.

Using Angular

I switched

from: import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

to: import { Geolocation } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation/ngx';

So, a plugin change worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

The error appeared because you use “navigator.” in front of you getCurrentPosition. Which will cause the WebView to ask for permission like a website would and you url is “://“ for fixing this you could use Cordova Geolocation plugin which enables the navigator to work with showing app name instead of “://“. Otherwise you should change & remove “navigator.” And use Geolocation with @capacitor/geolocation.