# How can I change "://" in mobile get access notification?

Tags: capacitor, ionic5, yandex-maps

Angular 12

Ionic 5

Capacitor 3

I use angular8-yandex-maps in ionic application.
How can I change "://" in notification?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:// Would Like To Use Your Current Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312167/would-like-to-use-your-current-location)

Comment: I use angular8-yandex-maps, and get two alert. First alert from Geolocation, and second from my question.

Comment: You can't, it's a bug on WKWebView, if you (or angular8-yandex-maps) use web geolocation it will show that prompt when requesting the geolocation permission